# SSO Cookie Encryption in Python

Tags: python, cookies, encryption, single-sign-on, rsa

I'm trying to generate authenticate a user on a separate server (run by a different company):

https://www.example.com (my site)
https://forums.example.com (forum instance run by company)

To perform this authentication they have an option to accept encrypted SSO cookies with the following options:

- **Cookie Name:** test
- **Encoding:**
  None
  **Base64**
  Url
- **Encryption Algorithm:**
  AES
  **RSA**
- **Cipher:**
  AES/CBC/NoPadding
  AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding
  AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding
  **RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding**
- **Key to Decrypt the Cookie:**
  upload file (private_key.pem)
- **Process Block Size After Byte Array:**
  false
- **Data Type:**
  plain
  **json**
  xml

I've tested this implementation without the encryption and it works so I know the issue isn't the JSON but rather the encryption. I've made several attempts to encrypt the cookie and pass it along, but the forum site fails to decrypt the cookie regardless of the various implementations. Here's what I've got right now:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import RSA
from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_v1_5
import base64

def login(request):
    key = RSA.generate(2048)
    pubKey = key.publickey()
    privKey = key.exportKey('PEM') // save into private_key.pem and uploaded

    msg = '{"id": 1, "user": "jdoe"}'

    cipher = PKCS1_v1_5.new(pubKey)
    emsg = base64.b64encode(cipher.encrypt(msg))

    response = redirect("https://forum.example.com")

    response.set_cookie("test", emsg, secure=True, httponly=True, domain="example.com")

    return response
```

Comment: Can I assume the company has given you their public key, which you'd use to encrypt the data you send? The code sample above shows you creating a keypair.

Comment: The company allows you to upload the key to decrypt the cookie. So I created a key pair, kept the public key for the encryption and uploaded the private key "private_key.pem".

Comment: Could you try `PKCS1_OAEP` instead of `PKCS1_v1_5`? It probably won't work either, but worth a shot. Also, can you verify that *you* can decrypt the cookie? Do you get any specific error when the cookie fails to decrypt?

Comment: I did also try `PKCS1_OAEP` and it did indeed fail. I unfortunately don't get any errors when the cookie fails, it just redirect to the remote SSO login, which results in an endless loop.

Comment: Does the company have public documentation on their scheme? I don't see an integrity check (HMAC or similar) -- might they be expecting additional data?

Comment: Not much more than what I already provided. http://docs.answerhub.com/articles/1427/how-to-enable-configure-the-cookie-sso-authenticat.html look under **Configure SSO Cookie Handling**

Comment: There are two main ssue with the overall approach 
- a domain cookie is used, hence it will be sent to any host in the cookie domain which offers TLS 
- once issued the cookies is most likely out of control

Instead of doing this in a proprietary way it might be better to agree upon a standard ... here OpenID Connect which offers JWT-base IdTokens and it has a UserInfo endpoint where the token can be validated